# Scheduling a notification?

Tags: java, android, push-notification, android-notifications

Is there any way to schedule a notification to appear at a specific time?

I am developing an app that reminds a user to change their bandage every 6/12 hours and I wish to send a notification to the user 6/12 hours after they confirm that they have applied the bandage.

Is there any way to do this? I have tried to implement the alarmManager Class however every example I have found uses a specific time of the day as opposed to 6/12 hours after an event.

Comment: use Alarm Manager
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an app which checks whether to show a notification every 24 hours. You can change it to whatever interval you would like.

```
with(context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager) {
    // Create a PendingIntent which AlarmManager would raise.
    // You should have a BroadcastReceiver to receive the intent and send a push notification.

    setInexactRepeating(
        AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
        startAt.toEpochSecond() * 1000,
        intervalInMillis,
        pendingIntent
    )
}
```

`startAt` -> Epoch when your alarm should start working (preferably in future). If this is in past, it will immediately boradcast the intent.

`intervalInMillis` -> Interval in milliseconds. For your case this should be 6 hours.

If your app requires different alarms (notifications) at 6 and 12 hours, I would still go with 6 hours or even 3 hours as the interval. When the broadcast is received, you should check if the app is supposed to send a notification or not. If not, don't do anything.

Read more about [Scheduling repeating alarms](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms).

Note: `AlarmManager` is affected by doze mode and you need to reset all your alarms after the phone restarts. Clubbing this with `WorkManager` would be ideal. But this should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

**Schedule tasks with WorkManager**
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/

Previously firebase-jobdispatcher-android was working fine now google introduced new WorkManager for scheduling task.

**Here is a simple implementaion**

http://thetechnocafe.com/how-to-use-workmanager-in-android/

Comment: This seems a lot easier to implement than the alarm manager, the WorkManager comes with a handy Initial Delays feature, which will let me delay the task for as long as I want before it executes. Thanks.